# Spring 4: What is the right @PreAuthorize authentication expression for a POST request?

Tags: spring-security, spring-el, spring-rest

In my Spring Rest app I have an extension of the CrudRepository interface. Onto that I am applying security. Here is my current version for Option objects:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="option", path="option")
public interface OptionRepository extends CrudRepository<Option, Long> {

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("#id == principal.id || hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public Option findOne(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @PreAuthorize("#entity.id == null || #entity.id == principal.id || hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public Option save(@Param("entity") Option entity); 
}
```

This works for:

- GET /option/1 for ordinary user with (id = 1) (doesn't have ROLE_ADMIN).
- GET /option/2 for ordinary user with (id = 1) returns HTTP 403
- GET /option/any for an admin user (has ROLE_ADMIN).
- PUT /option/1 for ordinary user with (id = 1).
- PUT /option/2 for ordinary user with (id = 1) returns HTTP 403
- PUT /option/any for an admin user.
- POST /option for ordinary user with (id = 1) returns HTTP 403
- POST /option for an admin user.

For PUT the annotations `#entity.id == principal.id` and `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')` are working OK. But for the user POST /option that fails the error message from the server is:

```
{
↵  "timestamp" : 1503449641093,
↵  "status" : 403,
↵  "error" : "Forbidden",
↵  "exception" : "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException",
↵  "message" : "Access is denied",
↵  "path" : "/option"
↵}
```

I figured that a POST has no ID value.  So in my @PreAuthorize for save() I speculatively added the `#entity.id == null`.  This has no effect on my problem.

My question: How can I protect the PUT with ID values and also allow a POST to succeed?

Thanks,

Jerome.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? Having a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688463/haspermission-on-repository-save-method-does-not-get-called-with-new-record

Comment: I never got a good answer for this. I'm guessing I'm asking too much of that API.  In its place I created a DAO answer.  See a complete implementation at https://github.com/logicaltiger/exchangeboard  .